# Update mongoose connection credentials when secrets are rotated

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, typegoose

I have a Node.js / Nest.js web service, connected to a MongoDB using typegoose / mongoose. The app runs in a K8s container alongside a Vault service that periodically rotates the mongoDB client's credentials.

In my app, I have a service that watches for changes to the database secrets, and then creates a new mongoose connection whenever they change. The best we've come up with here is basically this (logging / error handling omitted for readability):

```
@Injectable()
export class MongoConfigWatcher {
   constructor(
      @InjectConnection() private readonly connection: Connection,
   ) {
      fs.watchFile(MONGO_CREDFILE, () => this.connect());
   }

   private async connect() {
      const uri = getUri(MONGO_CREDFILE);
      await this.connection.close();
      await this.connection.openUri(uri, options);
   }
}
```

This strategy has generally worked fine for us, but the problem is that if there happen to be simultaneous requests or already-running database operations, race-condition errors can crop up. For example where the connection is closed before a db operation is complete, or a new db operation starts before the connection has been re-established. These are rare, but are causing us problems.

I feel like there aught to be a better way to do this - ie. updating the credentials without having to manually close the connection (which may be busy doing work!), so that the reconnection happens AFTER any running queries are finished and BEFORE any new queries start.

Any better approaches or ideas on how to this properly?

Answer (score 0):

A better approach will be listening to the disconnecting event from the mongoose connections.

```
this.connection.on('disconnected', async () =>  {
        console.log('Mongoose default connection disconnected');
        fs.readFile(MONGO_CREDFILE, async () => {
        await this.connect();
      }})
```

This is better since you don't need to wait for the credentials to change. Instead, once a connection (out of the mongoose connection pool) starts disconnecting you will reconnect with the current credentials.